# How to make structure fields programmable in matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct, field, cell

I have a excell file that I need to read into matlab. I already read excel file as cell form in matlab.
I want to convert cell data type to structure in matlab. My excel file is like this

```
       Va   Ia   Vb   Ib   Vc   ... ... 
01:00  100  10   200  20   300  ... ...    
02:00  110  11   210  21   310  ... ...    
03:00  120  12   220  22   320  ... ...    
04:00  130  13   230  23   330  ... ...    
...    ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ... ...
```

and then I know taht structure data type consist field and material. I wanna that first column use to field name. for instance, I want this

```
structure A
field 1: Va
material : [100;110;120;130 ... ...]
field 2: Ia
material : [10 ;11 ;12 ;13  ... ...]
```

and I will use that to access variables in structure

```
A.Va(3)= ~~~~~ ;somethig.....
```

Comment: The question is unclear to me.

Comment: .... I'm sorry what?  Can you please rephrase your question?  I have no idea what you have just said.

Comment: If you want the first column (i.e. values/strings 01:00, 02:00) be used as indices or keys, than [Map](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/map-containers.html) is the way to go.

Comment: You need to use [dynamic field names](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).